# ES6 Feature: How are Template Strings useful?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-interpolation

AKA Template Literals, String Interpolation. ([Wiki here.](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/es6/template-strings/))

Why are they useful?

When should I not use them?

How are these features similar and different from using JSX with React?

How can I use [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw) effectively as mentioned in the bottom of the wiki?

Comment: It's good to remember that everything that you can do in ES6, you can do in ES5, just in a more ugly fashion. Building up in HTML in ES5 is a miserable affair, using +=  and nesting in variable concatenation inside the template build up. It's a QOL thing more than anything.

Comment: JSX has nothing to do with strings. Apples and oranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string templating (or string interpolation) feature is ubiquitous in many programming languages. You should use it when you have a distinct or recurring template that you wish to fill in with the variables in current scope. It makes the template more readable than concatenation of strings or `printf`-style formatting.

The difference with JSX is that JSX is intended for templating HTML, whereas string templates are for templating any kind of text, for instance, log messages or user output.

The raw strings may be useful when you wish to operate on a string that has a lot of actual backslashes, not escaping backslashes. For instance, if you want to describe a string `\n\r\u0000`, then you would write it as `\\n\\r\\u0000`, which is not very readable. With raw strings, you can write it as `String.raw('\n\r\u0000')`.

Answer (score 5):

They make the code more readable. For example:

```
// ES6
let fruit = 'apples'
console.log(`I like ${fruit}.`)
```

The ES5 equivalent:

```
// ES5
var fruit = 'apples'
console.log('I like ' + fruit + '.')
```

The multiline feature is also convenient for writing large blocks of words:

```
// ES6
console.log(`string text line 1
string text line 2`)
```

The ES5 equivalent:

```
// ES5
console.log("string text line 1\nstring text line 2")
```

Template strings should always be used if variables are present.

Answer (score 2):

That code is more readable without terminating strings and append variables.

```js
var links = [{
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  name: "Google"
}, {
  url: "http://www.yahoo.com",
  name: "Yahoo"
}, {
  url: "http://www.bing.com",
  name: "Bing"
}];

var output = "<ul>";

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {

  output += `
      <li><a href="${links[i].url}">${links[i].name}</a></li>
   `;

}

output += "</ul>";
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="output">


</div>
```

Comment: If one uses ES2015 strings interpolation then there is no reason to not use `for-of`. `for (let link of links) ...`

Answer (score 0):

#### Use 1

It's multiline. (In JS, norm strings need backslashes before newline chars.)

---

#### Use 2

An alternative style. Compare:

```
a: ${a}, b: ${b}, c: ${c}, d: ${d}, e: ${e}
```

.with:

```
a: '+a+', b: '+b+', c: '+c+', d: '+d+', e: '+e
```

.And compare:

```php
function generated_function(){
    '+ statement1 +'
    '+ function2_name +'();
    f3();
    f'+ 5*5 +'();
}
```

.with:

```
function generated_function(){
    ${statement1}
    ${function2_name}();
    f3();
    f${ 5*5 }();
}
```

---

#### Nicety

It's backslash-escaped too—<${> by <\${> or <$\{>.

---

#### Nb

It's different to <String.raw>. Cf [§](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44607569/632951).